# error:incompatible types:android.content.Context can not be converted to com.firebase.client.core.Context

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

in my populateviewholder override method, I used

`viewholder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());`

but here `getApplicationContext()` doesn't work, the cursor mark that  wrong 1st argument.

Comment: You used the wrong import in the ViewHolder class for Context

Comment: how I fixed it? remove import and context,and again add??

Comment: You need to import `android.content.Context` instead of the Firebase one

Comment: thanks brother..maybe I got it